# Angular 5 + Spring boot image upload

Tags: java, typescript, spring-boot, angular5

I am trying to upload an image from angular to spring boot rest. but it throws

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException: Current request is not a multipart request
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.java:190) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
```

I am new to both the technologies. Help me upload the file.

Here is the code.

**RestController**

```
public ResponseMessage addUser(@RequestParam("profileImage") MultipartFile profileImage,
    @RequestParam("user") User user) {

try {
    if (userService.doesUserExist(user.getUsername())) {
    return new ResponseMessage("The username is not available; please choose a different username", 200);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(profileImage.getOriginalFilename());
storageService.storeFile(profileImage, user.getUsername() + "." + extension, profilePicturePath);
user.setProfilePicturePath(profilePicturePath + "/" + user.getUsername() + "." + extension);
userService.addUser(user);

return new ResponseMessage(user.getUsername() + " was added successfully!", 200);
}
```

**Angular Service**

```
addUser(user:User,profileImage:File){
      const formData:FormData = new FormData();

     formData.append('profileImage', profileImage);
     formData.append('user',JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user)));

     return this.http.post<ResponseMessage>("/api/admin/user/new_user",formData,this.postHttpOptions);

    }
```

**Angular Component**

```
setImage(files:FileList){
    this.newProfileImage = files.item(0);
  }
upload(){
if (this.newUser.password == this.newUser.confirmPassword) {
      this.userService.addUser(this.newUser,this.newProfileImage).subscribe(
        res => {
          this.responseMessage = res;
          alert(this.responseMessage.message);
        },
        err => {
          alert("Error Adding the user: " + err.message);
        }
      );
    }
}
```

**Angular Template**

```
<input type='file' id="imgInp" (change)="setImage($event.target.files)" />
```

Comment: plz share complete stacktrace, and the `curl` that is being requested from angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

The changes I made..

1. Instead of @RequestParam I added @Requestpart
2. Instead of @RequestParam User user I added @RequestPart String user; then converted String to user using ObjectMapper.
3. On the client side, I removed'ContentType = application/Json' and mentioned no content type

Here is the code

```
public String addUser(@RequestPart("profileImage") MultipartFile profileImage,
        @RequestPart("user") String userString) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

    User user = new ObjectMapper().readValue(userString, User.class);
}
```